# Highest RabbitMq compatibility as Message Bus for Spring XD 1.3.0.RELEASE

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-xd

I'm trying to figure out what the highest version of RabbitMq that I can use with Spring XD 1.3.0.RELEASE.

Basically we are using Rabbit as a message bus in Spring XD. Also we are using it as a source or sink (custom modules) in some streams.

Current version we are using is RabbitMq 3.6.10

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect any problems using it with the latest release (currently 3.7.15).